Maximum entropy distributions with more general constraints
Gibbs showed that for a space $X$ (assume finite for simplicity) and functions $f_i:X\to R$, the maximum entropy distribution on $X$ s.t. constraints on the expectation of $f_i$ is the Boltzmann distribution. That is: let $p = \arg\max_p H(p)$ s.t. $E_p[f_i(X)] \leq F_i$ (or equality) for constants $F_i$. Then $p(x)\propto \exp(\sum_i\lambda_i f_i(x))$.
Do we have solutions for more general constraints on $p$, i.e. not of the form $E_p[f_i(X)]$?
Any pointer to such a result would be appreciated.
